# Powerhsell + HTMl Formatting

Tags: html, powershell

I need some help here. I have the below Powershell code which I use to generate a HTML Table with Database Size and Names.

Now the output is good and everything looks better.. But sinew I have got over 500 Databases my boss has to scroll a lot to read the data,

I was thinking if there is a way I can put it in a column.

Something like this

```
Mbx001  MBX002 MBX003 MBX004
2.1 GB  3.2 GB 4.5 GB 10.8 GB
```

here is the power shell code

```
$dbreport = Generate-ReportHeader "dbreport.png" "$l_db_header"

$cells=@("$DB Name","Database Size")
$dbreport += Generate-HTMLTable "Database Overview" $cells

$databases = get-mailboxdatabase -status | sort
$currentDate = Get-Date

foreach ($database in $databases)
{
    $dbname = $database.name
    $dbserver = $database.server
    $dbsize = $database.DatabaseSize
    $pf = (Get-MailboxDatabase "$database" | get-mailbox -ResultSize   Unlimited).count


    $cells=@("$dbname","$dbsize")
    $dbreport += New-HTMLTableLine $cells

    $dbsizeges = $dbsizeges + $database.databasesize
    $gespf = $gespf + $pf


    $dbsizegb= $dbsize.Split(' ')[0]
    $dbvalues += @{$dbname=$dbsizegb}
}

$dbreport += End-HTMLTable

$cells=@("DatabaseCount","Database Size","Database Overall Count")
$dbreport += Generate-HTMLTable "$l_db_summary" $cells

$anzdb = $databases.count

$cells=@("$anzdb","$dbsizeges","$gespf")
$dbreport += New-HTMLTableLine $cells
$dbreport += End-HTMLTable

new-cylinderchart 500 400 Database Name Size $dbvalues     "$tmpdir\dbstat.png"

$dbreport += Include-HTMLInlinePictures "$tmpdir\dbstat.png"

$dbreport | set-content "$tmpdir\dbreport.html"
$dbreport | add-content "$tmpdir\report.html"
```

Here is the Functions File

```html
#HTML Tables #-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- # HTML Header function New-HTMLHeader ($title) { $HTMLHeader = "
<html>

<head>
  <title>$title</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div align=` "center`">
    <table style=` "width: 90%; text-align: left; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; border-collapse:collapse; font-family:calibri;`" border=` "0`" cellpadding=` "0`" cellspacing=` "0`">
      <tr>
        <td style=` "background-color: `#0072C6; color: `#ffffff; font-weight: bold; border:solid `#0072C6; border-width: 3px 3px 3px 3px; width: 100px`">
          <img src=` "cid:reportheader.png`" alt=` "picture`">
        </td>
        <td style=` "background-color: `#0072C6; color: `#ffffff; font-weight: bold; border:solid `#0072C6; border-width: 3px 3px 3px 3px; font-size: 20px`">Exchange Report</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <table align=` "center`" cellspacing=` "0`" style=` "width: 80%`">
      <td style=` "background-color: `#F8F8F8; color: `#585858;`">

        Exchange Report for $orgname
        <br>Exchange Reporter
        <br>

        </tr>
      </td>
    </table>
    &nbsp; "#" return $HTMLHeader } # Table function Generate-HTMLTable ($headline, $cells) { $HTMLTable = "
    <h3 style=` "text-align:center; font-family:calibri; color: `#0072C6;`">$headline</h3>
    <table style=` "width: 80%; text-align: left; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; border-collapse:collapse; font-family:calibri;`" border=` "0`" cellpadding=` "0`" cellspacing=` "0`">
      <tr>"#" foreach ($cell in $cells) { $HTMLTable += "
        <td style=` "background-color: `#0072C6; color: `#ffffff; font-weight: bold; border:solid `#0072C6; border-width: 3px 3px 3px 3px;`">$cell</td>" } $HTMLTable += "</tr>" return $HTMLTable } # New Table function New-HTMLTableLine ($cells) { $NewTableLine = "
      <tr>" foreach ($cell in $cells) { $NewTableLine += "
        <td style=` "background-color: `#F8F8F8; color: `#585858; border:solid `#0072C6; border-width: 1px 1px 1px 1px;`">$cell</td>" } $NewTableLine += "</tr>" return $NewTableLine } # Table function End-HTMLTable () { $TableEnd = "</table>" return $TableEnd } # HTML End function End-HTML () { $HTMLEnd = "
</body>

</html>
" return $HTMLEnd } # HTML Inline Pictures function Include-HTMLInlinePictures ($picid) { $htmlreport = "
<table align=` "center`" cellspacing=` "0`" style=` "width: 80%`">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <center>
        " $Pics = Get-ChildItem "$picid" -name Foreach ($pic in $Pics) { $htmlreport += "
        <img src=` "cid:$pic`" alt=` "picture`">" } $htmlreport += "
      </center>
  </tr>
  </td>
</table>
" return $HTMLReport } # Report Header function Generate-ReportHeader ($Image, $Headline) { $ReportHeader = "
<br>" $ReportHeader += "
<table style=` "width: 90%; text-align: left; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; border-collapse:collapse; font-family:calibri;`" border=` "0`" cellpadding=` "0`" cellspacing=` "0`">" $ReportHeader += "
  <tr>
    <td style=` "background-color: `#0072C6; color: `#ffffff; font-weight: bold; border:solid `#0072C6; border-width: 3px 3px 3px 3px; width: 100px`">
      <img src=` "cid:$image`" alt=` "picture`">
    </td>
    <td style=` "background-color: `#0072C6; color: `#ffffff; font-weight: bold; border:solid `#0072C6; border-width: 3px 3px 3px 3px; font-size: 20px`">$headline</td>
  </tr>
</table>
" #" return $ReportHeader } # Report Footer function Generate-ReportFooter () { if ($language -match "DE") { $footer = " &nbsp;
<table align=` "center`" cellspacing=` "0`" style=` "width: 80%`">
  <tr>
    <td style=` "background-color: `#F8F8F8; color: `#585858;`">

      Exchange Reporter $reporterversion
      <br>


    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td style=` "background-color: `#F8F8F8; color: `#585858;`">

      <center>

        <hr>Spenden Sie etwas für die Weiterentwicklung, wenn Ihnen Exchange Reporter gefällt:
        <br>


      </center>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
&nbsp; "#" return $footer } else { $footer = " &nbsp;
<table align=` "center`" cellspacing=` "0`" style=` "width: 80%`">
  <tr>
    <td style=` "background-color: `#F8F8F8; color: `#585858;`">

    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td style=` "background-color: `#F8F8F8; color: `#585858;`">

      <center>

        <hr>

      </center>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
&nbsp; "#" return $footer } }
```

Comment: what is the question?

Comment: @jisaak He is asking to transpose the output. _I was thinking if there is a way I can put it in a column._.

Comment: You have several functions here that are not included in your code. That would mean we cannot reproduce this or tell you what to change if the issue is in those functions.

Comment: Thanks Guys. i have added the functions file I used

Comment: Hey Guys. Did anyone had a chance to look at it please...